# Importing one DOMDocument into another

Tags: php, dom, domdocument, php-7

I am attempting to merge 2 html documents, A and B. A should basically integrate B.
Consider the following code:

```
$domA = new DOMDocument();
$domA->loadHTMLFile('foo/bar/A.html');

$domB = new DOMDocument();
$domB->loadHTMLFile('foo/bar/B.html');

$elementToReplace = /*some element in $domA*/;

$domA->importNode($domB, true); /*<-- error occuring here: Node Type Not Supported*/
$domA->replaceChild($domB, $elementToReplace);
```

I don't really understand why importNode wouldn't work on a DOMDocument object as it is a subclass of DOMNode in PHP, which the importNode()-function requires as an argument. ([importNode()](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.importnode.php), [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php))

I have already been looking at some of the similar questions but wasn't able to find anything that would have helped me in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use the DOMDocument `$domB` as the imported node, instead you need to import the content - `$domB->documentElement` is the root element.

A quick example (with comments) as to how to use it...

```
$domA = new DOMDocument();
$domA->loadHTMLFile('a.html');
$domB = new DOMDocument();
$domB->loadHTMLFile('b.html');

// Find the point to replace with new content
$elementToReplace = $domA->getElementById("InsertHere");

// Import the base of the new document as $newNode
$newNode = $domA->importNode($domB->documentElement, true);
// Using the element to replace, move up a level and replace
$elementToReplace->parentNode->replaceChild($newNode, $elementToReplace);
echo $domA->saveHTML();
```

with a.html...

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <div id="InsertHere" />
</body>
</html>
```

and b.html

```
<div>New content to insert</div>
```

Will give ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><head></head><body>
  <html><body><div>New content to insert</div></body></html>
</body></html>
```

Note as you are using `loadHTMLFile()` it has wrapped even the small fragment of HTML into a full page.  If instead you use...

```
$domB->load('b.html');
```

the result is...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><head></head><body>
  <div>New content to insert</div>
</body></html>
```

Note that using `load()` though is loading XML and is much less forgiving of the document structure than it's `loadHTML()` counterpart.

Comment: Thank you very much for such an elaborate answer!
I tested it with your variant and it worked perfectly :)

What I still don't understand is, why importNode() is not able to take a DOMDocument as an argument as it is inheriting from DOMNode... is that me not understanding OOP or is it something internal in PHP?